# Headers in robotframework 4

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to learn data driven testing with Robotframework, I am currently running version 4.0.1 and python version 3.9.4 on a windows 10 machine.

But I suspect that the syntax I am using is for a older version of robotframework.

I am using a external file to set up my steps, I then import it in my actual testcase file.

I am getting errors when I try to write additional header info for my *** Test Cases ***
This is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Resource    ../Resources/login_resources.robot
Suite Setup    Open my Browser
Suite Teardown    Close Browsers
#Test template to use
Test Template    Invalid login


*** Test Cases ***      username        password

Right user empty password   admin@yourstore.com   ${EMPTY}    
Right user wrong password   admin@yourstore.com   xyz
Wrong user right password   admin@yourstore1.com   admin
Wrong user empty password   admin@yourstore1.com   ${EMPTY}
Wrong user wrong password   admin@yourstore1.com   xyz


*** Keywords ***
Invalid login
    [Arguments]    ${username}  ${password}
    Input User Name     ${username}
    Input Pwd   ${password}
    Click Login Button
    Error message should be visible
```

So the whole section of *** Test cases *** is now in red:

```
*** Test Cases ***      username        password
    
    Right user empty password   admin@yourstore.com   ${EMPTY}    
    Right user wrong password   admin@yourstore.com   xyz
    Wrong user right password   admin@yourstore1.com   admin
    Wrong user empty password   admin@yourstore1.com   ${EMPTY}
    Wrong user wrong password   admin@yourstore1.com   xyz
```

What would be the correct syntax so all scenarios could be under one test case?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem, please show the error message of the framework. Your first code example runs fine for me in Robot Framework 4.0 your second example has indentation errors. If you want 1 test case, then remove the first column, define a single test with a template and remove the `Test Template` from the Settings table.

Comment: Actually the issue was that I had a empty  *** Test Cases *** heading in my resource file.
The test cases are now passing but the test data for username is marked red and marked with Keyword definition not found, but the test cases are passing :)

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your IDE. It is suggested to use the .resource file extensions with resource files, that way the framework will give error in such cases.

Comment: I am using PyCharm 2021.1.1 Community Edition, I changed the resource files to the .resource, but that made something crash with the IDE, I have used .robot for resource files before without error, anyways, at least the test cases are working :)

Answer (score 0):

It's IDE issue not robotframework. If you are using [Intellibot plugin](https://github.com/mtrubs/intellibot) it's not maintained since 2018 and it has 73 open issues. I have doubt that it will be fixed soon. I would recommend to change your IDE which has maintained Robotframework plugin.